# Salesforce .net Integration

Tags: .net, web-services, salesforce, integration, outbound

I have written a webservice in .net that receive the outbound message from salesforce. With the Id received from the Salesforce outbound message, I want to query the related objects and its fields. Can I achieve this without salesforce authentication? With the session id I get from outbound message can I query the objects? I am confused. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Use the server URL and the session ID that are sent with the outbound message to make partner API calls back into Salesforce.

You will not need to call login again on the partner API. Just set the session id in the header and send the requests to the server URL.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Daniel. Could please tell me or post me a sample of how to pass those values?

Answer (score 0):

To integrate Salesforce with .NET you can use for example ADO.NET Provider for Salesforce.

This is a commercial product, but it supports all the functionality you need:

- authorization via Session Id
- executing SQL queries to Salesforce objects and their fields